# Memory Error When Generating List of Odd Numbers

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x

Please take a look at the following code. It makes a list of all odd numbers from 1 - 100. It then takes that list and chunks it into sublists, each sublist one element larger than the last.

```
mylist = list(range(1, 100, 2))
out = []
i = 1 # Start off with size 1, because we don't care about the initial empty list
tri = 0
while tri+i < len(mylist):
    tri = i*(i+1)//2 # Get sum of 0+1+2+..+i
    out.append(mylist[tri-i:tri])
    i+=1
print(out)
```

I'd like to create a function using this code that takes an input (n) that will correspond to the (n-1)th index of the new list of sublists (out) and sum all the elements in that sublist. I've taken input n and raised it to the power of itself plus 1 (n**(n+1)), but I keep getting memory errors past n = 5. Here's my experimental code that produces the error.

```
n = 10
mylist = list(range(1,n**(n+1), 2))
out = []
i = 1
while len(mylist):
    out.append(mylist[:i])
    mylist = mylist[i:]
    i+=1
print(sum(out[n-1]))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 2, in <module>
MemoryError
```

Edit (Clarifying Info): I'd like to create a function that when given an input (n), it will then go to the n-1 index of this list of sublists and sum the elements of the list. I'm working on a python challenge question and it was presented as a number triangle of odd numbers where the top of the pyramid is 1, then the next row is 3 and 5, and so on. So if given n, go to nth row in the triangle and sum the numbers of that row. Hope this helps to explain.

Edit 2: To get the sum of the nth row of a number triangle starting with one and incrementing by 1, the following code passed testing. However, this will not work for number triangles made from all odd, all even, or any non single incrementing series of numbers:

```
def triangle_row_sum(n):
    last_in_row = sum(range(1, n+1)) 
    first_in_row = last_in_row - (n-1) 
    p = sum(range(first_in_row, last_in_row + 1)) 
    return p
```

However, I am still working on a solution for an odd number triangle beginning with 1.

Comment: I'm incredibly confused by this code. This code just tries to sum the 9th element of `out` (which actually will be an error once the code gets there). But `out` is just the same list. You're creating an enormous list in memory and then directly copying it to another ENORMOUS list in memory. What are you actually trying to do? This entire code could be replaced with `print(19)`.

Comment: Sounds like the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378) to me. I agree with Morgan, what is your end goal? Sample input/output

Comment: But, having said all that, yes, you will get memory errors if you try to make a list with 50 billion items in it.

Comment: I'd like to create a function that when given an input (n), it will then go to the n-1 index of this list of sublists and sum the elements of the list. I'm working on a python challenge question and it was presented as a number triangle of odd numbers where the top of the pyramid is 1, then the next row is 3 and 5, and so on. So if given n, go to nth row in the triangle and sum the numbers of that row. Hope this helps to explain.

Comment: So, `f = lambda lst, n: sum(lst[n-1])`? What does the list of 50 billion numbers have to do with that?

Comment: Please update your question with that information. That was very helpful.

Comment: @MorganThrapp Thanks for the suggestion. So given n in the overarching function where your new lambda function would exist under, I don't know how to produce the correct "lst" argument needed for the function you suggested. But yes, that's precisely what I need to do.

Comment: @acecabana That's a different question then. Do you need a large list? Or do you need "a function that when given an input (n), it will then go to the n-1 index of this list of sublists and sum the elements of the list.".

Comment: @MorganThrapp He's not on the right track, generating a massive array in memory is not the correct approach to this problem.

Comment: The challenge doesn't provide the list as an input we can pass as an argument. As far as I can tell, we have to produce the list of lists of odd numbers and then sum the (n-1)th index of the list of sublists. Thanks for the prompt response.

Comment: See my answer, feel free to comment if you have questions. Show some work and I'll update it with more information. I have a working solution.

Comment: Did you figure it out? Any additional questions?

Comment: Haven't figured it out yet. Still trying to figure out how to get the function to recognize of numbers in the nth row of the odd number triangle.

Answer (score 2):

As this is a challenge, I'll point you in the right direction:

You don't need to store the triangle in memory. What you want is to figure out how to calculate what numbers are in the triangle at a specified line:

```
1)    1
2)   2 3
3)  4 5 6
4) 7 8 9 10
```

If I want line 4, that starts with the 7th number in the list and ends with the 10th. Is there a way, for line `n`, to figure out what the `start` number and `end` numbers are. Then you don't have to store the tree in memory, you can just calculate the starting and ending numbers, then add them up.

Comment: `i = sum(range(1, n+1))
m = i - (n-1)
p = sum(range(m, i + 1))
return p`

Comment: Is that your attempt? Update your question with what you've tried and what issues you're having.

Answer (score 0):

For a triangle of odd numbers, at the nth line, the first number would be n*(n-1)+1. After that you can generate the series of n odd numbers in that line easily and sum them up.

`sum([n*(n-1)+1+2*i for i in range(n) ])`

This will give you the sum of nth line in a triangle of odd numbers.

For a triangle of even numbers, the sum of the nth line would be

`sum([n*(n-1)+2*i for i in range(n) ])`